# Using Excel to capture URL redirects

Tags: microsoft-excel, redirection, url, vbscript

In Excel is it possible to have a list of URLs in column A and have a column B auto-populate with the URL of the page you get to if you click the link in Column A.

(I would like to audit all the 301/302 redirects currently on one of my sites)

Comment: Excel is not the tool for this. You want something like `curl $1 -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'`

Answer (score 0):

Linux will be a big help here:

Create a script file called `fetch_redirects`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url
do
    echo -n "$url,"
    curl "$url" -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'
done < "${1:-/proc/${$}/fd/0}"
```

<sub>Make sure to mark it executable</sub>

Then, given a list of urls, one per line in `urls.txt`, execute:

```
cat urls.txt | fetch_redirects > redirects.csv
```

You can then open `redirects.csv` in Excel or any other tool which supports CSV files.

Comment: An equivalent batch solution using curl.exe can also be cooked up of course if required.

Comment: @Karan By all means please edit it into the answer beside the bash script! :) I'm just not as well versed in batch scripting. >.<

Comment: Might do so later, although going by the recent edit above looks like the OP would prefer a VBScript/VBA solution.

Comment: Yes please Karen.

Comment: I've found the following which checks to see if a URL exists (i.e. looking for a status code of 200) 
`Function HttpExists(sURL As String) As String

Dim oXHTTP As Object

Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")



If Not UCase(sURL) Like "HTTP:*" Then

sURL = "http://" & sURL

End If



On Error GoTo haveError

oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", sURL, False

oXHTTP.send

HttpExists = IIf(oXHTTP.Status = 200, "Page is Live", "redirects or 
missing")

Exit Function

haveError:

HttpExists = "redirects or missing"

End Function`

Comment: So basically I want to check for oXHTTP.Status = 301 and if that's true return the location it redirects to.